# Глубина поиска алгоритма Minimax для игры крестики-нолики python

Tags: python, алгоритм, разработка-игр

Не получается сделать глубину поиска лучшего решения, чтобы уменьшить силу Компьютера в игре "Крестики-Нолики". Что делал: пытался добавить проверку на переменную

```
if MAX_DEPTH == depth:
    return alpha
```

но всегда сталкиваюсь с проблемой при `MAX_DEPTH = 2`, что

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tic-tac-toe_v3.py", line 455, in <module>
    startGame(FIELD)
  File "tic-tac-toe_v3.py", line 417, in startGame
    moveComputer('X', FIELD)
  File "tic-tac-toe_v3.py", line 282, in moveComputer
    x ,y = search(letter, FIELD, -1, 1, 0)
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

Но при попытке `MAX_DEPTH` увеличить, сила ПК сразу возрастает.
Полный код: https://github.com/Pypylex64/tic-tac-toe-minimax/blob/main/tic-tac-toe.py

Comment: Функция search у вас возвращает число (одно число, не кортеж), его нельзя распаковать в две переменные x и y, поэтому и вылетает с ошибкой на строке `x ,y = search(letter, FIELD, -1, 1, 0)`. Проверка, о которой вы в начале пишете, на это никак не влияет.

Comment: @insolor спасибо за ответ. Да, я это прекрасно понимаю, вот поэтому и спрашиваю как реализовать глубину, ибо понял что так она возвращает кортеж, а через глобальную переменную у меня тоже никак не выходит. Правильно я мыслю, что переменная `depth` мне как-то в этом поможет?

Comment: "так возвращает кортеж" - не возвращает кортеж, во всех return там возвращается просто одно число, насколько я увидел. Чтобы возвращала кортеж, нужно функцию search переделать, чтобы возвращала два числа.

Comment: @insolor я имел ввиду возвращает кортеж при `depth == 0`. Я пытался так же сделать через глобальные переменные `BEST_X, BEST_Y = 0, 0`, а сама функция `search()` чтобы возвращала одно число `alpha`, но беда в том, что на каком-то из этапов эти переменные оставались такими же, как и в предыдущем скажем вызове (3, 2 к примеру)